# Call to undefined function pg_connect() ошибка

Tags: php

База данных postgresql установлена на одном сервере. PHP установлена на другом сервере.

Через Navicat подключаюсь к БД без проблем, даже из дома.

Но вот PHP говорит `"Fatal error: Call to undefined function pg_connect()"`

Вырезка из php.ini:

```
;extension=php_pdo_oci.dll
;extension=php_pdo_odbc.dll
extension=php_pdo_pgsql.dll
;extension=php_pdo_sqlite.dll
extension=php_pgsql.dll
;extension=php_shmop.dll
```

На запрос:

```
echo extension_loaded('pgsql') ? 'yes':'no';
```

Отвечает `no`

Папка расширений указана верно, так как mysql работает.

Думаю это связано с тем что postgresql установлена совсем на другом сервере. Может я ошибаюсь

из phpinfo()

```
Server API - Apache 2.0 Handler
Virtual Directory Support - enabled
Configuration File (php.ini) Path - C:\Windows
Loaded Configuration File - D:\web\php\php.ini
```

Про postgresql там ничего нет. В папку C:\Windows пробовал класть php.ini

из httpd.conf

```
LoadFile "D:/web/bin/libpq.dll"

LoadModule php5_module "D:/web/php/php5apache2_4.dll"
PHPIniDir "D:/web/php"
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
```

Comment: php.ini который лежит в D:/web/php имеет подключение модуля постгреса?

Comment: Я не знаю, как это проверить? Вот что есть:
[PostgreSQL]
pgsql.allow_persistent = On
pgsql.auto_reset_persistent = Off
pgsql.max_persistent = -1
pgsql.max_links = -1
pgsql.ignore_notice = 0
pgsql.log_notice = 0

Comment: extension=php_pgsql.dll что-то вроде этого

Comment: Выше написано же Вырезка из php.ini:

Comment: Я про это и хотел уточнить. Вырезка из файла D:/web/php/php.ini, верно? И еще глупый вопрос: апач после подключения постгреса в пхп рестартовался?

Comment: Да, верно, Апач Конечно рестартовал

Comment: Срочно нужна помощь!!!

Comment: Олег, я не работаю с Апачем и пхп на винде, поэтому возможно не знаю каких-то особенностей. Что если вызвать phpinfo() через Апач, там про постгрес что-нибудь будет?

Answer (score 0):

Все решил проблему. Помогда dll-ка от следующей версии php. Скачал дистрибутив на официальном сайте php, вытащил оттуда dll-ку и все заработало. Всем спасибо!